# Searching Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics by Number

Tags: research-process, mathematics, journals, website, springer

The volumes in the Springer LNM series are usually referred to by number, and there are now thousands of them. However, I have not been able to find any way on the Springer website to go directly from the volume number to the SpringerLink page for the book. For example, if someone tells me that some piece of information can be found in LMN 800, my goal is to go from this information to the SpringerLink page https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0091027. However, the only way I know how to do this is to first Google "Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics 800," and (for me at least) navigate to the second page of results where I find the actual title of the volume, and then use Google or the Springer website to get the actual Springer Link page. Is this basically the only way to do it, or is there a centralized place where this information can be found in one step ?  For now I have just found the website http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/toc/lnm1970.html, but it seems to mostly only have a few years from 1970 to 1974.

Comment: "The volumes in the Springer LNM series are usually referred to by number" Since when?! I have published a volume in LNM and I don't even remember its number in the series. I've always referred to books by their titles and authors. In what context have you had to search for a book only knowing that it was in LNM and its number in the series (no author, no vague notion of the topic of the book...)?

Comment: @N.I.: Sorry !  I shouldn't have used the word "usually". It just so happens that someone recently referred me to a book by its LMN number and gave me no information other than that. I found it eventually but it left me wondering ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/index.html), you can search using the "Series" field. If you type "Lecture Notes in Mathematics" there, you get a list of all volumes. Adding the number seems to directly bring you to the correct entry.

Comment: Great !  I don't know why I didn't think of that.